# How do I set the timezone for a published calendar in Office365?

Tags: exchange, calendar, office365, time-zone

I have a calendar published (not shared) on Office365. When viewing the published version of the calendar appear 4 hours later than they should be. The HTTP view of the published calendar does not say what timezone it's displaying but it seems a reasonable guess that there's a timezone setting somewhere.

This is only affecting one user account but that user account's timezone seems to be set correctly according to both Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration and Get-MailboxCalendarConfiguration.

The HTTP view of the calendar is not using the Office365 user account's timezone, nor is it using the timezone of the computer viewing it. What other timezone related settings could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from PowerShell by using this line:

```
Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration -Identity {calendar's identity} -TimeZone "Pacific Standard Time"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the timezone on **Outlook client** will use **PC's timezone** settings. For **OWA client**, it will use the **timezone setting of mailbox** (i.e. Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration).

Secondly, **the time of shared calendar will display as timezone for current client/ mailbox** (i.e. who open this shared calendar). However, we can **check the timezone** of shared calendar by **open a calendar item**. 
Figure as below:
[image]

Comment: Clarification: it's a published calendar, not a shared calendar. A published calendar is accessible via two HTTPS URLs. One is a .html file that can be displayed in a browser, and one is a .ics file can be displayed in most calendar software. In this case the .ics URL shows the calendar with the correct timezone and the .html URL shows the same calendar with the wrong timezone. Neither the Outlook client nor OWA client are involved in viewing the .html URL.